# AWS CLI listing all the files within a S3 Bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

I am practicing AWS commands. My client has given me the AWS IAM access key and the secret but not the account that I can log in to the admin panel. Those keys are being used with the project itself. What I am trying to do is that I am trying to list down all the files recursive within a S3 bucket.

This is what I have done so far.

I have configured the AWS profile for CLI using the following command

```
aws configure
```

Then I could list all the available buckets by running the following command

```
 aws s3 ls
```

Then I am trying to list all the files within a bucket. I tried running the following command.

```
 aws s3 ls s3://my-bucket-name
```

But it seems like it is not giving me the correct content. Also, I need a way to navigate around the bucket too. How can I do that?

Comment: what do you mean,  aws s3 ls s3://my-bucket-name
 is not giving the correct content? what is missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to list all of the objects recursively but aren't using `--recursive` flag. This will only show prefixes and any objects at the root level

Relevant docs https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/ls.html

Comment: Thanks. This helps. I had to run aws s3 ls s3://eastwestrail-staging --recursive.

Answer (score 0):

A few options.

### Roll your own

if you run an `aws s3 ls` and a line item has the word "PRE" instead of a modify date and size, that means it's a "directory" that you can traverse. You can write a quick bash script to run recursive `aws s3 ls` commands on everything that returns "PRE" indicating it's hiding more files.

### s3fs

Using the S3FS-Fuse project on [github](https://github.com/s3fs-fuse/s3fs-fuse), you can mount an S3 bucket on your file system and explore it that way. I haven't tested this and thus can't personally recommend it, but it seems viable, and might be a simple way to use tools you already have and understand (like `tree`).

One concern that I might have, is when I've used software similar to this it has made a lot of API calls and if left mounted for the long-term, it can run up costs just by the number of API calls.

### Sync everything to a localhost (not recommended)

Adding this for completion, but you can run

```sh
aws s3 sync s3://mybucket/ ./
```

This will try to copy everything to your computer and you'll be able to use your own filesystem. *However*, s3 buckets can hold petabytes of data, so you may not be able to sync it all to your system. *Also*, s3 provides a lot of strong security precautions to protect the data, which your personal computer probably doesn't.